# Logit with dummies when certain number of dummies must be used

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, stata

In Stata 12, I'm using logit to model a process that is successful or fails and requires seven workers. I have a larger pool of potential workers and am using dummies to signify which seven individuals were working on the process, which resulted in a success or fail. So the coefficients will report the impact each individual worker will have on probability of success if they are included.

However, (again) this process **requires** seven workers. All of the observations show exactly seven of the 30-something worker dummies activated. In reality, it doesn't make sense to imagine the addition or removal of a worker - the process will be fundamentally different if only six workers are present. My results can still show the relative impacts across workers, but I'm worried about the conceptual problem of having only six workers.

I would be interested in comparing the impact of each worker relative to some "average" or "benchmark" worker, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Is it infeasible to transform your problem to use dummies standing for each possible combination of seven workers? That way, you're guaranteed that you are always comparing a group of seven to a group of seven. The problem would be the combinatorial explosion.

Comment: @Wayne, "The problem would be the combinatorial explosion". Indeed, ${30\choose 7} = 2035800$ ;-). Of course, you could always just create dummies for the combinations that exist... still, this asks a different question, whether the combinations differ, rather than the contribution of each individual to the group. What's important to determine here is which question you want to answer.

Comment: @gung: I missed the *30* part. But as I read the question more carefully I'm not sure what's being asked. I'm not sure how a number of workers other than 7 becomes an issue, since the all training data will have 7 non-zero dummies.

Comment: @gung: I'm interested in knowing individual workers' contribution to the likelihood of success.

Comment: When I get results, the interpretation of the coefficients is, holding all other factors equal (including other workers), adding a certain worker will change the likelihood by a certain amount.

The problem is, in this case, you never simply add or remove a worker; you always substitute them with another one. I guess I'm just concerned how I should interpret my results.

Answer (score 4):

If the additive model's a good fit there isn't any problem. You *could* use it to make predictions for success of the process with six, eight or two dozen workers; but you *needn't*, just as if the ambient temperature were a predictor you shouldn't be tempted to use the model to predict success of the process at -50°C or 300°C. If Smith's the reference level, then when you substitute him with Jones, Jones' coefficient gives the change in the logit; when you substitute Jones with Brown, the difference between Brown's & Jones' coefficients gives the change in the logit.

You could pick a typical worker as the reference level, or use effect (sum-to-zero) coding, if you think it aids interpretation. The coding scheme makes no substantive difference to the model.